# How to programmatically change the checked status of a lightning:input checkbox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller

I have a toggle in my cmp and I'd like to be able to switch it back off in case of need. (I.e some error happens)

in my cmp file:

```
<div class="animals_container">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.animals}" var="ca">
            <lightning:card iconName="standard:scan_card" >
                
                <aura:set attribute="title">
                    <a href="{!'/' + ca.Id}">{!ca.Name}</a>
                </aura:set>
                             
                <div class="toggle_div" data-animal_id="{!ca.Id}">
                    <lightning:input type="toggle"
                                     id="{!ca.Id}"
                                     label="Sold?"
                                     name="sold_toggle"
                                     checked="{!ca.Sold__c}"
                                     onchange="{!c.toggleAnimalSoldJS}" />
                </div>     
                
            </lightning:card>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
```

my js method from the controller.js:

```
toggleAnimalSoldJS : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.toggleAnimalSoldApx");
        
        action.setParams({
            "animalId": event.srcElement.dataset.animal_id
        });
        
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // do nothing          
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                // toggle it back off here in case something happens
                console.error(response.getError());
            }
            helper.showToast(component, event, helper, state);
        }));
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

On a side note, I do know that I should use the helper file to store all this code and keep the controller cleaner, I first want to get this working before doing so.

Thank you.